# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while trying to read from a directory in windows

Tags: python, keras, filenotfounderror

The directory of the folders is: C:\Pet_Classification\data\train. Below is the code snippet.

```
train_data_dir = 'C:/Pet_Classification/data/train'

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Got the below error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-536baa9a7d03> in <module>
      3     target_size=(img_width, img_height),
      4     batch_size=batch_size,
----> 5     class_mode='binary')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in flow_from_directory(self, directory, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation)
    990         follow_links=follow_links,
    991         subset=subset,
--> 992         interpolation=interpolation)
    993 
    994   def flow_from_dataframe(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in __init__(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation, dtype)
    408         subset=subset,
    409         interpolation=interpolation,
--> 410         **kwargs)
    411 
    412 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/directory_iterator.py in __init__(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation, dtype)
    113         if not classes:
    114             classes = []
--> 115             for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    116                 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
    117                     classes.append(subdir)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Pet_Classification/data/train'
```

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the file really doesn't exist. How do you know that it does? Are you missing an extension?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find you file as the path isn't reachable.

```
import os

#Gets your current Directory    
print('getcwd:      ', os.getcwd())

#Gets your current Directory 
print('__file__:    ', __file__)

# train_data_dir = 'C:/Pet_Classification/data/train'
```

Get the current working directory and try from there.

```
 train_data_dir = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Current working directory shouldn't matter if the drive and full path are specified as they are here.

Comment: Thank you on checking the current directory found that it was not pointing correctly. hence changed the path and it worked fine.